# A column that auto increments in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to create a column that auto increments from 1- (however number of rows there are). However, I need the column to reorder itself depending on the Order of my probability column. Is is possible?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe an `AFTER INSERT` trigger could do the trick...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff. There's a column of IDs and a column of probabilities for each ID. I need a new column with integers from one to the # of IDs in the ascending order of the probabilities. So basically my new column that I want will be auto_increment in the ascending order based on the probability column.

Comment: @TheImpaler triggers cannot modify tables involved in the query triggering them, which always includes the table they are "on".

Comment: @Uueerdo Makes total sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd generally recommend against implementing that kind of ordering calculation as an explicit table field. Keeping such information up to date would create more and more overhead as the table grows. Instead, you could just ORDER BY your probability column; or if you really need the "rank" in the query result, there are a number of ways to do that, something like this should work:

```
SELECT @seq := seq + 1, d.*
FROM theRealData AS d, (SELECT @seq := 0) AS init
ORDER BY theRealData.probability
;
```

---

Pseudo code (i'm not looking up exact syntax as I write this, so it there might be some things I overlook) for the stored procedure I mention in the comments below (may need adjustments if I have the ordering reversed.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE theProc (newID INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE newProb INT; //Not sure if it is int, but for the sake of example
   DECLARE seqAt INT;
   SET newProb = SELECT probability FROM theTable WHERE ID = newID;
   SET seqAt = SELECT IFNULL(min(seq), 1) FROM theTable WHERE probability > newProb;
   UPDATE theTable SET seq = seq + 1 WHERE seq >= seqAt;
   UPDATE theTable SET seq = seqAt WHERE ID = newID;
END
```

If you pass all the fields inserted, instead of just the new row's id after it is inserted, then the procedure can do the insert itself and use last_insert_id() to do the rest of the work.

Comment: Do you know another way? That doesn't work for me. For the type of table I'm doing, I'm only going to insert one more row into the table and rank that data compared to the data already in the table.

Comment: Single (presumably infrequent) inserts can make performance less of a problem; you could create a stored procedure to update the ordering. It could be called after the insert, or you could use it to do the insert AND the reordering.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the primary key values can become very expensive, specially if you have related tables that point to it.

If you need to keep an order by probability, I would suggest adding an extra column with the `probability_order`. You can update this column after every insert or every minute, hour or day.

Alternatively, as @Uueerdo says you can just use `ORDER BY` when querying the table rows.